# Odd characters typed when launching vi

Tags: vim

On one of my WSL2 ubuntu 20.04 installations every time I launch vi/vim (vim.basic) I get extra characters

```
:bfbf/bfbf/bfbf^G
```

I have deleted my .vimrc, copied a .vimrc from another machine that works fine, removed the global vimrc.  Nothing gets rid of this, and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

I have searched every file in ~/ and /etc for "bfbf" and the only file that has it is .viminfo (in my command history).  I also tried deleting the .viminfo and it didn't help.

[image: VIM - Vi IMproved version 8.1.3741]

Comment: Is your $TERM properly set?